# Autounattend.xml Issue (Disk Configuration) with Windows Server 2016 on Dell PowerEdge R330

Tags: raid, unattended, windows-server-2016, dell-poweredge

I'm having some issues getting an unattend file working with Server 2016 Essentials. I'm working with a Dell PowerEdge R330 with a PERC 330 RAID adapter (currently all drives in the machine are in a single RAID 5 array). I'm running the entire thing off of an .iso on which I placed the autounattend.xml and compile with ImgBurn (using what are supposedly the appropriate settings for a bootable Windows install disk). As can be seen in the XML, I had this generated from [this website](http://windowsafg.no-ip.org/server2016.html).

Here's the contents of the autounattend.xml (I tabbed out the most relevant parts):

```
<!--*************************************************
Windows Server 2016 Answer File Generator
Created using Windows AFG found at:
http://windowsafg.no-ip.org

Installation Notes
Location: 
Notes: Enter your comments here...
**************************************************-->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
<settings pass="windowsPE">
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SetupUILanguage>
<UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
</SetupUILanguage>
<InputLocale>0c09:00000409</InputLocale>
<SystemLocale>en-US</SystemLocale>
<UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
<UILanguageFallback>en-US</UILanguageFallback>
<UserLocale>en-US</UserLocale>
</component>
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ImageInstall>
<OSImage>
<InstallTo>
<DiskID>0</DiskID>
<PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
</InstallTo>
</OSImage>
</ImageInstall>
<UserData>
<AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
<FullName>User</FullName>
<Organization></Organization>
<ProductKey>
<Key>XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX</Key>
</ProductKey>
</UserData>
<EnableFirewall>true</EnableFirewall>
<DiskConfiguration>
    <Disk wcm:action="add">
        <CreatePartitions>
            <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                <Order>1</Order>
                <Size>350</Size>
                <Type>Primary</Type>
            </CreatePartition>
            <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                <Extend>true</Extend>
                <Order>2</Order>
                <Type>Primary</Type>
            </CreatePartition>
        </CreatePartitions>
        <ModifyPartitions>
            <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                <Format>NTFS</Format>
                <Label>System</Label>
                <Order>1</Order>
                <PartitionID>1</PartitionID>
                <TypeID>0x27</TypeID>
            </ModifyPartition>
                <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                <Order>2</Order>
                <PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
                <Letter>C</Letter>
                <Label>OS</Label>
                <Format>NTFS</Format>
            </ModifyPartition>
        </ModifyPartitions>
        <DiskID>0</DiskID>
        <WillWipeDisk>true</WillWipeDisk>
    </Disk>
</DiskConfiguration>
</component>
</settings>
<settings pass="offlineServicing">
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-LUA-Settings" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<EnableLUA>false</EnableLUA>
</component>
</settings>
<settings pass="generalize">
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SkipRearm>1</SkipRearm>
</component>
</settings>
<settings pass="specialize">
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<InputLocale>0409:00000409</InputLocale>
<SystemLocale>en-US</SystemLocale>
<UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
<UILanguageFallback>en-US</UILanguageFallback>
<UserLocale>en-US</UserLocale>
</component>
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP-UX" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SkipAutoActivation>true</SkipAutoActivation>
</component>
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-SQMApi" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<CEIPEnabled>0</CEIPEnabled>
</component>
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ComputerName>-PC</ComputerName>
</component>
</settings>
<settings pass="oobeSystem">
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<AutoLogon>
<Password>
<Value></Value>
<PlainText>true</PlainText>
</Password>
<Enabled>true</Enabled>
<Username>User</Username>
</AutoLogon>
<OOBE>
<HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
<HideLocalAccountScreen>true</HideLocalAccountScreen>
<HideOEMRegistrationScreen>true</HideOEMRegistrationScreen>
<HideOnlineAccountScreens>true</HideOnlineAccountScreens>
<HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
<NetworkLocation>Work</NetworkLocation>
<ProtectYourPC>1</ProtectYourPC>
<SkipMachineOOBE>true</SkipMachineOOBE>
<SkipUserOOBE>true</SkipUserOOBE>
</OOBE>
<UserAccounts>
<AdministratorPassword>
<Value></Value>
<PlainText>true</PlainText>
</AdministratorPassword>
<LocalAccounts>
<LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
<Description>User</Description>
<DisplayName>User</DisplayName>
<Group>Administrators</Group>
<Name>User</Name>
</LocalAccount>
</LocalAccounts>
</UserAccounts>
<RegisteredOrganization></RegisteredOrganization>
<RegisteredOwner>User</RegisteredOwner>
<DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet>false</DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet>
<TimeZone>Central Standard Time</TimeZone>
</component>
</settings>
</unattend>
```

The error I'm getting is this:

> Windows could not set the id for a partition on disk 0. The error occurred while applying the unattend answer file's  setting. Error code: 0x80042565

Contents of x:\Windows\Panther\setuperr.log:

```
2017-08-02 14:10:01, Error [0x0606cc] IBS SetPartitionType: Either the partition style for the request [MBR] is either unknown, or does not match the style of the specified partition [MBR].[gle=0x000036b7]
2017-08-02 14:10:01, Error [0x0606cc] IBS SetPartitionType: ChangePartitionType failed, hr = 0x80042565.[gle=0x000036b7]
2017-08-02 14:10:01, Error [0x0606cc] IBS ApplyDiskOperationUsingService: Failed to correctly apply disk operation of type [0xb]; hr = 0x80042565[gle=0x000036b7]
2017-08-02 14:10:06, Error [0x06048f] IBS CallBack_DiskConfiguration_ApplyUnattend:An error occurred while applying unattend disk configuration; hr = 0x80042565
```

Things I've tried:

- Removing "0x27" (line 62) (gives a different error)
- Adding "Yes" after line 61 (for the first 'system reserved' partition" (gives a different error)
- A host of other things I've found online that give a host of different errors

Also should note that if I boot to the original iso it has no problems seeing the drives and I can install everything fine.

Any ideas would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Does [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/df523791-7424-4be7-b468-548bbd0c95ed/discconfiguration-error-0x80042565?forum=w8itproinstall) help?

Comment: Nope, already tried everything in that thread!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this AutoUnattend is set up for BIOS boot method.  If you're using UEFI, you'll get exactly that error.

Try replacing the `<DiskConfiguration>` section with the following:

```
<DiskConfiguration>
                <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
                <Disk wcm:action="add">
                    <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                    <WillWipeDisk>true</WillWipeDisk>
                    <CreatePartitions>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>1</Order>
                            <Size>350</Size>
                            <Type>EFI</Type>
                        </CreatePartition>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>2</Order> 
                            <Type>MSR</Type> 
                            <Size>128</Size> 
                        </CreatePartition>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>3</Order> 
                            <Type>Primary</Type> 
                            <Extend>true</Extend> 
                        </CreatePartition>
                    </CreatePartitions>
                    <ModifyPartitions>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>1</Order> 
                            <PartitionID>1</PartitionID> 
                            <Label>System</Label> 
                            <Format>FAT32</Format> 
                        </ModifyPartition>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>2</Order> 
                            <PartitionID>3</PartitionID> 
                            <Label>Local Disk</Label> 
                            <Letter>C</Letter> 
                            <Format>NTFS</Format> 
                        </ModifyPartition>
                    </ModifyPartitions>
                </Disk>
            </DiskConfiguration>
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your answer would be more complete if you could comment on what exactly this code does to answer the OP's question. Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 0):

I tested @William's solution and it worked ok in my use case. The only missing step is that the DiskID value within the  section  should be aligned with DiskID value within

```
       <DiskConfiguration>
            <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
            <Disk wcm:action="add">
                <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                <WillWipeDisk>true</WillWipeDisk>
                <CreatePartitions>
                    <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                        <Order>1</Order>
                        <Size>350</Size>
                        <Type>EFI</Type>
                    </CreatePartition>
                    <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                        <Order>2</Order>
                        <Type>MSR</Type>
                        <Size>128</Size>
                    </CreatePartition>
                    <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                        <Order>3</Order>
                        <Type>Primary</Type>
                        <Extend>true</Extend>
                    </CreatePartition>
                </CreatePartitions>
                <ModifyPartitions>
                    <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                        <Order>1</Order>
                        <PartitionID>1</PartitionID>
                        <Label>System</Label>
                        <Format>FAT32</Format>
                    </ModifyPartition>
                    <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                        <Order>2</Order>
                        <PartitionID>3</PartitionID>
                        <Label>Local Disk</Label>
                        <Letter>C</Letter>
                        <Format>NTFS</Format>
                    </ModifyPartition>
                </ModifyPartitions>
            </Disk>
        </DiskConfiguration>
                    <ImageInstall>
                            <OSImage>
                                    <!-- Selecting OS version-->
                                    <InstallFrom>
                                            <Path>install.wim</Path>
                                            <MetaData>
                                                    <Key>/IMAGE/INDEX</Key>
                                                    <Value>2</Value>
                                            </MetaData>
                                    </InstallFrom>
                                    <!-- /Selecting OS version-->
                                    <InstallTo>
                                            <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                                            <PartitionID>3</PartitionID>
                                    </InstallTo>
                            </OSImage>
                    </ImageInstall>
```